# Fluxbox Sytem Tray adding more and more whitespace

Tags: fluxbox

My problem is, that some apps seem to remove their needed space in the system tray after remving the icon.

For example, when plugging/unplugging my AC, the xfce-powermanager icon changes and adds whitespace to the tray.

Is there a way to configure the System Tray, so it notices the empty space? Restarting Fluxbox works, but that seems a very hackish way.

[image: Fluxbox System Tray Whitespaces]